# expressjs, difference on middleware callback use

Tags: node.js, express

A simple Express app:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

function test (req, res, next) {

}
```

I'm trying to figure out the difference on these two implementations:

```
router.use('/myRoute', test)

router.post('/myRoute', function (req, res) {

});
```

And:

```
router.post('/myRoute', test, function (req, res) {
});
```

What I understand from the documentation (https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#middleware-callback-function-examples) and (https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.use) there is none. But that can't be the case?

Comment: Just did a edit, it was a typo. It's the same route.

Comment: In that case: `use` kicks in for all HTTP verbs, and `post` only for HTTP POST calls, so in the first example `test` will run for all HTTP calls irrespective of whether they're get, post, options, etc. etc. In the second, you've set up a route *only* for post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you put as an example there's a difference:

```
router.use('/myRoute', test)
```

This will apply the "test" function to whatever request comes to /myRoute (POST, PUT, GET, etc).

While this:

```
router.post('/myRoute', test, function (req, res) {
});
```

Will only be applied to the POST request to /myRoute.

As for your question, the difference is that you either apply it globally, for example or you apply it only to a specific function. Depends the case you will use one or the other.

Comment: The first example will trigger for requests that _start_ with `/myRoute`, so `/myRoute` but also `/myRoute/foo`, `/myRoute/foo/bar`, etc.

Comment: And the middleware function will be called at the same level in the hierarchy, in both of those implementations? Because it feels like if I use router.use, this is called before router.post.

Comment: @gelv the one that you declare first will be called first.

Comment: middlewares are called in the order you declare them. Whatever way you chose to declare.

Comment: I hope this is ok to ask, but when I use the express-bodyparser and router.use(), it goes into that middleware too early, but it works when i use middleware in router.post(). So it feels that generally router.use() is called earlier then router.post(). (see my issue here: https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator/issues/379)

Comment: Well, sure you aren't defining the routes before you use the body parser? Are you using express-generator?